# how to display select2 after user input 3 data

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I have select2 here to display user email data, but  data can be up to tens of thousands, and that makes my select2 very slow, is there a method to only display after 3-letter user input?

this my script select2

```
$('#add_form').find("#list_user").select2({
                              width: "100%",
                              placeholder: "Choose User by Email...",
                              ajax: {
                                url: "{{ route('getuser') }}",
                                dataType: "json",
                                delay: 250,
                                processResults: function(data) {
                                  return {
                                    results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                                      return {
                                        id: obj.email,
                                        text: obj.email
                                      };
                                    })
                                  };
                                },
                              }
                            });
```

and this my controller

```
public function getUser(Request $request)
        {
            $search = $request->input('term', '');
            $user = DB::table('users.users')->where('email','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
                    ->get();
            return response()->json($user);
        }
```

Comment: The problem is simply due to the weight of the data. Adding 10,000 elements to the DOM (or even multiples of that as Select2 options contain 2 or 3 individual elements) will never be fast. I would suggest you instead use an auto-complete field and implement the search logic on your server via AJAX.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what do you think of the jquery autocomplete plugin? Can it solve my problem?

Comment: That would work, but implementing the autocomplete is only half the solution. As I mentioned, you'll need to write the controller logic to do the searching/filtering/paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only solution for your problem is to take only some records and display them. and then from select you need to call the controller to search data again and display it.

for that purpose you can change the your query to

```
user = DB::table('users.users')->where('email','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->take(10)->get()
```

for searchable select you can reference [this link](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) and this [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vg7pgbcb/1/)